# How can i deseralize a dynamic generated JSON Object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

Im having trouble to deserialize the object back into the original class. The problem is that the Component class have to be serialized in that spezific way with the features beeing a seperate list/set object.The attributes have to be seperate key/value pairs. If i try to deserialize the JSON/object back, i get an "can´t construct instance of LinkedHashMap" error.

Here is the class to parse to JSON

```
public class Component {
    private Set<Attribute> attributes;
    private Set<Feature> features;
}
```

```
public class Attribute {
    private String type;
    private String key;
    private String value;
}

public class Feature {
    private String key;
    private String value;
}
```

Here is the serializer

```
public class ComponentSerializer extends StdSerializer<Component> {
    public ComponentSerializer(){
        this(null);
    }

    public ComponentSerializer(Class<Component> c){
        super(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Component com, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        
        for(Attribute att : com.getAttributes()){
           gen.writeStringField(att.getKey(),att.getValue());
        }

        Set<Feature> features = new HashSet<Feature>();

        for(Feature ftr : com.getFeatures()){
            features.add(new Feature(ftr.getKey(), ftr.getValue()));
        }

        gen.writeObjectField("features", features);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
    
}
```

The outcome JSON is something like

```
{
    "Foo": "Fooo",
    "Bar": "Barr",
    ...
    "features": [
      {
        "key": "foo",
        "value": "bar"
      },
      {
        "key": "bar",
        "value": "foor"
      }
      ...
    ]
 }
```

My attempt on deserialization

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(p.getCodec().readTree(p).toString(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
});

    Set<Attribute> attributes = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Feature> features = new HashSet<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
       if (entry.getKey().equals("features")){        
        
        //Here i cant create the Set<Features> from the object without the exception
        continue;
       }
       attributes.add(new Attribute("", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, Object> map = mapper.readValue(p.getCodec().readTree(p).toString(), new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

        Set<Attribute> attributes = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Feature> features = new HashSet<>();

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getKey().equals("features")) {
                List<LinkedHashMap> featureList = (List<LinkedHashMap>) entry.getValue();
                featureList.stream().forEach(feature -> {
                    features.add(new Feature(feature.get("key").toString(), feature.get("value").toString()));
                });
                continue;
            }
            attributes.add(new Attribute("", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString()));
        }
```